# AWS DynamoDB Encryption - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to set encryption for DynamoDB using Ruby / Ruby on Rails?

Does aws-sdk provide it?

Should I do that on my own?

Or it is not possible?

**NOTE:** There will be few the same Rails app running parallel and connected to the same DynamoDB.

Comment: check out the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't encrypt data for you. You would have to handle the encryption and decryption in your DynamoDB client code. There is a [Java library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-java) for handling this, but I don't see one for Ruby.

Note that DynamoDB won't be able to perform meaningful queries against any fields that you have encrypted.

I would recommend using the AWS KMS service to manage the encryption key that your application uses to encrypt data before it inserts it into DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting critical fields with AWS KMS works well -- here's an example how to wrap it in a convenient module.

requires 
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0'

config/initializers/aws_kms.rb

```
# Helper for AWS KMS encryption / decryption:
#
# Example:
#
# cipherdata = Aws::KMS.encrypt('boring plain text')
#
# => "AQICAkSXnpkzAJrrzNcjlMxRK78jbKHnkPohQdSZ445Xv29z6C2ty433pG2rcs96IujEj4IXAa1rmSzJXfiQqw4LaFcluh3CYsFQOlOfhgh0LhPdiQhnIP7d0BzlIu3uRFzHLrhIpg2JssVsjnCLZstNkzerfiwYtGSNTpltVjaqJblz3kktSFNxnMoVOcJSlvTbuMdiD9yplGMDD3LC0YKjUZtEZIqEjt=="
#
# Aws::KMS.decrypt( cipherdata )
#
# => "boring plain text"
#
#
# Protects from AWS KMS calls if we are in TEST environment
#
module Aws::KMS

  def self.encrypt(plaintext)
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
      ['not_encrypted_in_test', plaintext].join('|') # faking encryption so we can test this without AWS
    else
      cipherdata = client.encrypt({
        key_id: ENV['KMS_ARN'],
        plaintext: plaintext,
      }).ciphertext_blob
      Base64.strict_encode64(cipherdata)
    end
  end

  def self.decrypt(ciphertext)
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
      ciphertext.split('|').second # faking decryption so we can test this without AWS
    else
      cipherdata = Base64.strict_decode64( ciphertext )

      client.decrypt({
        ciphertext_blob: cipherdata
      }).plaintext
    end
  end

  # this helper method can be called to check if the ENV variables are configured correctly:
  def self.setup_correct?
    plaintext = 'Hey, it works!'
    cipherdata = Aws::KMS.encrypt( plaintext )
    Aws::KMS.decrypt( cipherdata ) == plaintext
  end

  def self.client
    Aws::KMS::Client.new
  end

end
```